# Drag 'n drop a partir de div com collapse e position fixed

Tags: jquery, ui-draggable

Bom dia, estou querendo utilizar o `Jquery-Ui Draggable` para realizar o *drag 'n drop* a partir de um painel lateral. O problema é que este painel é sobreposto a página com um `position: fixed` e ao arrastar os elementos para fora, acontecem duas situações:

- Com a configuração padrão do *draggable*, os elementos não saem da `div` pai (painel);
- Ao setar algumas configurações na inicialização do *draggable*, eu até consigo arrastar os elementos para fora da `div`, porém o evento de *drop* em cima do `body` nunca é acionado.

Esta é a do que está ocorrendo quando tento arrastar os itens. Além de não ser possível soltá-los, a posição do mouse também fica incorreta.

[image: Imagem]

Essa é a configuração do draggable:

```js
$('.draggable-dash').draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  helper: 'clone',
  appendTo: '.dropdashboard',
  containment: 'body',
  //zIndex: 2500,
  scroll: false,
  cursorAt: { top: -5, left: -5 },
  start: function(){
    $(this).hide();
  },
  stop: function(){
    $(this).show()
  }            
});
```

Estou a alguns dias quebrando a cabeça com esse cidadão, caso alguém saiba como resolver, ficarei eternamente grato.

**EDIT 1 - Segue trecho do CSS e do HTML do painel**

```
.theme-panel {
    position: fixed;
    right: -175px;
    top: 150px;
    z-index: 1020;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 175px;
    transition: right .2s linear;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.theme-panel.theme-panel-lg .theme-panel-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```
<div class="theme-panel theme-panel-lg">
    <a href="javascript:;" data-click="theme-panel-expand" class="theme-collapse-btn" id="tourTema"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
    <div class="theme-panel-content">
        <h5>Indicadores</h5>
        <div class="theme-version draggitens">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 text-center draggable-dash">
                    <p><img src="./img/area-chart.png"></p>
                    <p>Indicador 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 text-center draggable-dash">
                    <p><img src="./img/bar-chart.png"></p>
                    <p>Indicador 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 text-center draggable-dash">
                    <p><img src="./img/dashboard.png"></p>
                    <p>Indicador 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 text-center draggable-dash">
                    <p><img src="./img/line-chart.png"></p>
                    <p>Indicador 4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 text-center draggable-dash">
                    <p><img src="./img/pie-chart.png"></p>
                    <p>Indicador 5</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 text-center draggable-dash">
                    <p><img src="./img/doughnut-chart.png"></p>
                    <p>Indicador 6</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar um `droppable` para poder soltar um elemento dentro dele. No elemento com `droppable` você pode dizer quais elementos ele aceita (no caso do exemplo, ele aceita elementos com o seletor `"#painel .draggable-dash"`) e você consegue executar alguma ação do evento `drop`, que é chamado quando algum elemento é *dropado* no container. Confira toda a documentação [aqui](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/).

Segue um exemplo:

```js
$(function(){
  
  $('.draggable-dash').draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    cursor: "move"
  });
  

  $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    accept: "#painel .draggable-dash",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
      $(this).append(ui.draggable[0]).css({left: 0, top: 0});
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#painel{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 200px;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}

.draggable-dash{
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#droppable{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#droppable .draggable-dash {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
  <div id="painel">
    <div class="draggable-dash">1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="droppable">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Eu já tenho o droppable declarado, mas o que ocorre é que o painel que possui os elementos está sobre a página (como se fosse um sidebar). Quando eu solto o elemento na div com o droppable ele dispara o revert

Comment: Neste exemplo que fiz o painel também está sobre a página (usando `position: fixed;`, igual você falou na pergunta). Você consegue colocar uma parte do seu código executando aqui?

Comment: Editei a pergunta e adicionei um trecho do CSS e do HTML, não consigo colocar todo o conteúdo por conta do arquivo CSS e das configurações no Javascript.